# How to add string/numerical sorting to QSortFilterProxyModel derived class

Tags: c++, qt

I have a class derived from `QSortFilterProxyModel`, however when I click on the tabs of the table view for sorting nothing happens. Any suggestions on how I can add sorting feature to my custom class that inherits from `QSortFilterProxyModel`?

Answer (score 1):

It is well explained in the Qt documentation. This [link](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#details) points to the Qt 4.8 online reference.

The sorting feature is achieved either by implementing `sort()` in your model, or by using a `QSortFilterProxyModel` to wrap the model.

According to the question you're using the second approach. The class `QSortFilterProxyModel` provides a generic `sort()` reimplementation and also allows to achieve custom sorting behavior by subclassing `QSortFilterProxyModel` and reimplementing the `lessThan()` method.

My suggestions:

1- Make sure the proxy model is acting like a proxy. (it is sitting in the middle of the view and the real model).

```
QTreeView *treeView = new QTreeView;
MyItemModel *sourceModel = new MyItemModel(this);
QSortFilterProxyModel *proxyModel = new QSortFilterProxyModel(this);
proxyModel->setSourceModel(sourceModel);
treeView->setModel(proxyModel);
```

2- Make sure to enable sorting in the view (the default value is `false`).

```
treeView->setSortingEnabled(true);
```

3- If you needed to reimplement a member, make sure you have done it correctly.

I hope this helps.